# The code stops running after the entering the values

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

class Complex
{
    private:
        double real;
        double imag;
        double modulus;

    public:
        Complex(){
            cout<<"Default constructor is called"<<endl;
        }
        Complex (double realIn, double imagIn){
            this->real = realIn;
            this->imag = imagIn;
        }
        Complex (const Complex &a ){
            real = a.real;
            imag = a.imag;
            modulus = a.modulus;
        }
        double getModulus(){
            return modulus = sqrt(real * real + imag * imag);
        }
        void display(){
            cout<<real<<" + "<<imag<<" i"<<endl;
        }
        bool operator > (const Complex &c1){
            return modulus > c1.modulus? true : false;
        }
        Complex& operator = (const Complex &c1){
            real = c1.real;
            imag = c1.imag;
            modulus = c1.modulus;
        }               
};

int main(){
    int num, i,j;
    double real, imag;
    cout<<" Input number of complex numbers: ";
    cin>>num;
    Complex* c[num];

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++){
        cout<<"Imput the real part of the complex number no."<<i+1<<endl;
        cin>>real;
        cout<<"Input the imagine part of the complex number no."<<i+1<<endl;
        cin>>imag;
        c[i] = new Complex(real, imag);
        c[i]->display();
    }
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++){
        for (j = i +1; j < num; i++){
            if (c[j]->getModulus() > c[i]->getModulus() ? true:false){
                if (true){
                   Complex* temp = c[j];
                   c[j] = c[i];
                   c[i] = temp;
            } 
            }
        }
    }
    system("CLS");
    cout<<"The decreasing order of the complex numbers is: "<<endl;
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++){
        cout<<i+1<<" : ";
        c[i]->display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I just starting to learn about OOP, in particular the overloading function. I am asked to read a list of complex numbers and print out in decreasing order (using their modulus to compare). However, it stops after I have entered all the complex numbers. There is no error so I don't know where I got it wrong. Please help me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, add

```
#include<cstdlib>
```

at the beginning of the source to use `system("CLS");`

Secondly, change

```
for (j = i +1; j < num; i++){
```

to

```
for (j = i +1; j < num; j++){
```

(increment `j` instead of `i`) to avoid making `i` too large.